# Приложение на C# не связывается с БД на другом компьютере

Tags: c#, база-данных, sql-server

проблема в том, что создал приложение WindowsForm на C#,прикрепил БД, она на SQLServer'e, при попытки открыть на другом компьютере конечно же нет связи с БД, т.к. там нет sqlserver'a и т.д., помогите реализовать так, что бы приложение работало на другом ПК

```
 sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
 string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\сисишарп\WorkingWithDB\registr.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
        sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
```

Ошибка" Для BeginExecuteReader нужно открытое и доступное подключение Connection. Подключение устанавливается

Answer (score 2):

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB
```

Вы здесь подключаетесь к БД `MSSQLLocalDB` на локальном компьютере. Вам нужно указывать ip-адрес, или доменное имя компьютера, где находится ваша база данных в случае запуска приложения на другом компьютере.
Например:

```
Data Source=192.168.0.4\MSSQLSERVER
```

---

Для подключения с другой машины вам нужен полноценный SQL Server, SQL Server Express LocalDB не будет работать в этом случае.

Comment: Так - `192.168.0.4\MSSQLLocalDB` - не получится :-) Нельзя подключиться к LocalDB на другом компьютере.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Вы уверены?
`<add name="MtrSalesContext" connectionString="data source=sr-dc-135.corp.gidroogk.com;Initial catalog=TEST; persist security info=True; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />` - Хотите сказать такой код не будет работать?

Comment: Если на sr-dc-135.corp.gidroogk.com нет серверной версии SQL Server - не должно.

Comment: sr-dc-135.corp.gidroogk.com в данном примере и есть адрес sql-сервера. И ответ я давал исходя из утверждения ТС'а "прикрепил БД, она на SQLServer'e".

Comment: Но при этом вы написали в ответе дефолтное имя инстанса LocalDB, вот я о чем

Comment: Присмотритесь внимательнее, LocalDB указан как пример кода автора, мой пример указан после слова "Например:".

Comment: Присмотритесь внимательнее, у вас до моей правки было написано в качестве напримера `192.168.0.4\MSSQLLocalDB`

Comment: Называться DB может как угодно, даже LocalDB.

Comment: Может. Но вероятнее всего будет называться MSSQLSERVER или SQLEXPRESS. Зачем путать читателя на пустом месте?

Comment: Мне наоборот кажется что вы своей правкой внесли путаницу- у ТС'а имеется настроенный SQL-сервер с существующей БД, у которой имеется определенное название.

Comment: Руководство по редактированию
► исправьте грамматические или орфографические ошибки

► уточните смысл, не изменяя его

► исправьте незначительные ошибки

► добавьте связанные ресурсы или ссылки

► всегда проявляйте уважение к автору

Comment: Кажется, вы не понимаете, что часть `MSSQLLocalDB` в адресе `(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB` - это вовсе не название БД! Это имя экземпляра. Более того: это имя экземпляра SQL Server LocalDB, а не SQL Server.

Comment: @Anamnian, MSSQLLocalDB  - это не "база данных". В строке подключения через \ указывается не "база данных", а экземпляр SQL. В случае полного SQL Server - это именованный экземпляр, который доступен по `МАШИНА\ЭКЗЕМПЛЯР` или `.\ЭКЗЕМПЛЯР`. В случае SQL Server LocalDB (как у топикастера) экземпляр будет доступен только по `(localdb)\ЭКЗЕМПЛЯР`, и только с локальной машины. К `(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB` нельзя подключиться с друго машины заменой на `МАШИНА\MSSQLLocalDB` - это будет попыткой подключения к экземпляру полного SQL Server с названием MSSQLLocalDB - а его у топикастера нет.

Comment: @PashaPash Ну мы не можем знать наверняка, какой тип `SQL Server`'а стоит у автора вопроса: "прикрепил БД, она на SQLServer'e" - из этого я сделал вывод что там именно MS SQL Server обычный, и измененным именем экземпляра `MSSQLLocalDB`

Comment: @Anamnian мы точно можем знать, что у топикастера есть экземпляр SQL Local DB, с именем (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB, и именно к нему он прикрепил БД - т.к. это явно видно по connection string, который он привел   в вопросе :). Причем это имя экземпляра SQL ServerLocal DB - стандартное. Полного экземпляра MSSQLLocalDB у топикастера с большой вероятностью нет - его надо поставить руками, и явно указать именно такое название - что странно в слуае, если топикастер явно вообще не понимает, чем LocalDB отличается от полного SQL.

Comment: @Anamnian т.е. проблема топикастера с большой вероятностью именно в том, что ему нужно поставить полный SQL Server, которого у него нет. И да, в этом случае совет "просто впишите имя машины вместо (LocalDB)" сбивает в толку - т.к. это просто не заработает.

Comment: @PashaPash с очень высокой вероятностью вы правы.

Comment: @Anamnian стоит дописать в ответ "для подключения с другой машины вам нужен полноценный SQL Server, localdb недостаточно"? это сделает его намного лучше и полностью решит проблему :) в ответе Andrey это есть, но там сам ответ странно оформлен.

Answer (score -1):

Так как деталей о том - какая версия `MSSQLServer`, что за сеть, как подключаетесь, Вы нам не дали, то смею предложить два варианта строки подключения:

```
1. Server=ServerAddress;Database=DataBaseName;User Id=Username; Password=Password;
2. Server=ServerName\InstanceName;Database=DataBaseName;User Id=Username;Password=Password;
```

Answer (score -2):

1. Настраиваете БД на своей машине, разрешая подключение по TCP/IP и подключаетесь. (Совет, не используйте стандартную авторизацию windows, задайте пользователя и пароль) И подключитесь.
2. Установите SQL сервер на требуемый компьютер, измените строку подключения на `string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\registr.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";`

Comment: connectionString у вас тоже приведен совсем не для подключения к другому компьютеру...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, Он приведён для подключения к локальному файлу базы данных. Это второй вариант, читайте внимательнее. Для подключения к удалённому серверу строка будет иной: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: А, понял. Но в таком случае нужно устанавливать не SQL Server, а SQL Server Local DB.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, При установке SQL Server поставьте галочку, где спрашивается про установку Local DB.

Comment: это должно быть в ответе

Comment: @PavelMayorov, Может мне ещё самому всё установить и настроить? Не нравится - дайте более подробный и раскрытый ответ.